# Unity3d: "random" transform position values on editor

Tags: unity

Run into some strange behavior on editor position values.

https://youtu.be/DUBpbOUkbfo

As you can see we have two cube object with colliders on both and rigidbody on parent.
After start play mode parent object editor values sets to some random numbers while `transform.localPosition` and `transform.position` is still `(0,0,0)`.

This somehow related to parent-child physics hierarchy but can't understand how.

Comment: That is almost certainly a value like `7.347982374e-10` (or `.0000000007347982374`) and is just a floating point error problem.

Comment: yep it is, seems somehow affects by physics components on objects

Comment: No. It is due to how floating point numbers are represented in binary. Unity's debug.log will only ever show you values accurate to `0.1` when logging vectors. The editor "hides" values when they differ by less than `epsilon` from what the user entered, but when something changes (for example, reparenting) that clean user-entered value is lost and the full decimal representation is displayed. Check what the full value is when it is "random" and you'll find that it is a vanishingly small value. This is a result of the math that handles local vs. worldspace conversions.

Comment: You can not and should not attempt to "fix" this.